# Distance between two Point with Latitude & Longitude in oracle DB

Tags: oracle, geometry, oracle-spatial

I need to calculate Distance between two location through Pl SQL Query. I had tried some Qry but not getting it.

for this we are using Query in SQL is as follows

```
SELECT ROUND(geography::Point(cast('19.2806118' as float),cast('72.8757395' as float) , 
4326).STDistance(geography::Point(cast('19.4482006' as float),
cast('72.7912511' as float), 4326))/1000,1) DIST
```

Result : 20.6

To Calculate the same in ORACLE Db I have found a solution over internet which is as follows

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_geometry(2001,4326,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 1),
sdo_ordinate_array( 19.2806118,72.8757395)),sdo_geometry(2001,4326, null,sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 
1),sdo_ordinate_array( 19.4482006,72.7912511)),1,'unit=KM') distance_km from dual
```

Result :  10.9271..

Please suggest the method which will give me result in KM as I am getting MS SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please suggest the method which will give me result in KM as I am getting MS SQL

Swapping parameter order `19.2806118,72.8757395` to `72.8757395,19.2806118`

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
   sdo_geometry(2001,4326,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 1),
                 sdo_ordinate_array(72.8757395,19.2806118)),
   sdo_geometry(2001,4326, null,sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1,1),
                 sdo_ordinate_array(72.7912511,19.4482006))
   ,1
   ,'unit=KM') distance_km 
from dual;
```

**Yields exactly the same result as SQL Server: 20.5657053685075**

**[db<>fiddle demo Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89e32b021a313e7538c771828cfe788e)**
**[db<>fiddle demo SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9034339a4e47936dab313ab57c8c443f)**

Or by using `sdo_point`:

```
SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
         sdo_geometry(2001, 4326,
                sdo_point_type(72.8757395, 19.2806118, NULL), NULL, NULL),
          sdo_geometry(2001, 4326,
               sdo_point_type(72.7912511, 19.4482006, NULL), NULL, NULL),
               1, 'unit=KM') distance_in_m
from DUAL;
```

---

SQL Server: `geography::Point ( Lat, Long, SRID )`

Comment: Thanks For solution I found it same in other question.